# Performance in Logic Apps for ForEach and Conditions

Tags: performance, azure-logic-apps

I have noticed execution time for simple Condition and ForEach actions in my Logic Apps has an peculiarly long run-time, even considering the scope of these actions taking into account all downstream actions.

In a simple case, my deepest scope action is a For Each:

[image]

Notice the For Each is a short as possible in number of iterations: only one record being processed. Each action inside is very brief. The two HTTP actions are 52 ms total:

[image]

The Set Variable action is 29 ms:

[image]

How am I to understand this sums up to 1.63 seconds in the For Each?

[image]

This seems very odd to me, even with the "scope" context of considering ForEach reporting on all downstream actions. It still feels like well over 1.6 seconds that should not be needed.

Answer (score 0):

There will always be some overhead for scopes (delta for the foreach job to wake up + read and aggregate action results + persist state).

There are changes you can make to optimize this, for example, if an array data is coming in from the trigger, "split-on" the array and have separate run process each item will have a better performance than "not-split on" and loop over the array using for-each.